# HTTP request from one Virtual machine to another

Tags: http, networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have started 2 virtual machines in my computer (using VirtualBox on Windows 8.1) in same time. On first i have Linux Debian with Apache http server. On second running Windows XP. Both networks are set as NAT.

Http request must have specific URL (for example: "xxx.local"). So when I try connect from my real computer to virtual machine with Linux server its easy and its work, there I add only redirect for domain "xxx.local" to virtual machine IP and everything working fine.

But I need send request and receive reply from second virtual machine with Windows XP.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Put the two machines in the same virtual network and access the server by its IP. If by _"there I add only redirect for domain "xxx.local" to virtual machine IP and everything working fine"_ you mean you  _edited your hosts file_, you can do the same on Windows XP. Anyway, offtopic for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it. There is important to set "host only network adapter" for both virtual machines (but not the same one!) with same IP radius. Then you set IP of server machine to target domain in host file and that is all.

Works fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional network adapters to both VMs attached to one host-only network.